# Error in Custom Error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a custom error page in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I enable the page by including the following in my Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Missing" />
</customErrors>
```

My error page is as follows:
    @model HandleErrorInfo

```
<h1 class="text-danger">Error</h1>
<h3 class="text-danger">
    An @Model.Exception.GetType().Name has occurred
    while processing your request.</h3>
<div>
    @Model.Exception.Message
</div>
```

This works most of the time.  However, when I get the following Exception:

> The model backing the 'SiteDatabase' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.

This causes there to be some error that makes the error page not display correctly and then the following text appears on the page:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>      Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

How do I go about debugging this?  I already walked through the template and there doesn't seem to be any errors...

Answer (score 0):

> The model backing the 'SiteDatabase' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database.

This error is deep in the Data Access layer. If you don't have multiple layers, check your Entity Framework related classes.

Your configuration is for your application to redirect when errors occur. But this error occurs even before your application is loaded to memory or it's so critical that it crashes the entire .NET application.

Your option is to create a static HTML page as default redirect as this answer indicated:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377463/3918598

Answer (score 0):

An error page should have the least amount of external dependencies as possible. Consider removing external dependencies to master pages, layout pages, css, javascript, and images. The reason for doing this is because when an error page is shown, you can't assume anything when it comes to the state of the application or the server. The database might be down, there might be a random runtime error, CDN's might be down, etc.

Try to have it be a static, all encompassing page if possible, similar to GitHub's error pages: https://github.com/asdfadsfasdfasdfasdfa

More info: https://github.com/styleguide/templates/2.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error handling page is redirecting to a controller, which then pass the model to razor view. The error happened indicated that Model object, which is HandleErrorInfo was not populated properly, e.g. Exception property wasn't populated with the exception.

I guess your error handling controller can handle razor view level error properly, but when it happens in deeper layers such as the one provided, which is a entities level error, your HandleErrorInfo wasn't populated properly.

To further check why, please upload the code in the controller?